# 'Trying to get property of non-object'

Tags: php

When i click the link on my site to go to a page , it gives me an error 500 message, when i check the error it comes back with

> Trying to get property of non-object' pointing towards 'return $next($request);',

please can someone help me out, thanks in advance,
Here is the page's code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class StaffAuth
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request by checking to see if the user is a member of Staff.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure                 $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (is_null($request)) {
            return redirect('/')->with('flash_error', 'Could not access, No Session Found.');
        }

        if (is_null($request->user())) {
            return redirect('/')->with('flash_error', 'You have been automatically logged out due to an extended period of inactivity.');
        }

        if (! $request->user()->isStaff()) {
            return redirect('/')->with('flash_error', 'Could not access, Permission Denied');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwtzO.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Post complete error with trackback code, so that we can provide a solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the error is where you're pointing. Probably these errors happen in blade views as you may trying to access a property of a null object.